# Passing parameters to controller's constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have a controller which has several methods which should all share common informations. Let's say my URI format is like this:

```
http://server/users/id/admin/index
http://server/users/id/admin/new
http://server/users/id/admin/list
http://server/users/id/admin/delete
```

I need to retrieve some informations from the database for `id` and have them available for all methods instead of writing a line in each of them to call the model. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class users extends Controller {

 private $mydata = array();

 function users()
 {   
     parent::Controller();
     ....

     $this->mydata = $this->model->get_stuff($this->uri->segment(2));
 }

 function index()
 { 
     $this->mydata; //hello data!
 }
```

Here I simply hardcoded the array (which probably is a really bad idea). Nevertheless you can store the data in a codeigniter session if you need to. Codeigniter can store this data in a cookie (if it's total is less than 4kb) otherwise you can store bigger blobs of data in the database (see the docs on how to do this).

See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Subsection: Saving Session Data to a Database

Here's some session exercise:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('mydata', $mydata);
....
$mydata = $this->session->userdata('mydata');
```

Answer (score 0):

If this cannot be solved from [CodeIgniters Hook mechanism](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), you could override the constructor method in your controller and call your own. Judging from [their SVN repository](http://dev.ellislab.com/svn/CodeIgniter/trunk/system/libraries/Controller.php) you'd probably would do something like

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    function YourController()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->_preDispatch();
    }

    function _preDispatch()
    {
         // any code you want to run before the controller action is called
    }
```

Might be that the call to preDispatch has to be before the call to parent. Just try it and see if it works. I didnt know they still use PHP4 syntax. Ugh :(

Comment: Well the problem is getting `id` into play: I know how to get it inside methods but not in the constructor. By the way, you can use PHP5 syntax too with codeigniter.

Comment: If CI's methods for getting the id are not available in the constructor yet, you can still parse it from the Request-URI in the  $_SERVER superglobal.

Comment: Yes I guess I could do that, I was looking for a cleaner solution than manually parsing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. After all that's what a framework should do.

Answer (score -2):

Based on your url structure, and the fact that codeignitor uses a MVC pattern, I'm assuming you're using mod_rewrite to format the url path into a query string for index.php. If this is the case, the value of "id" should be available at $_REQUEST['id'] at any point in the execution of the script...

Comment: Sorry, unfamiliar with codeignitor, just assumed based on all the structuring that it would use mod_rewrite. But you know what they say about assuming....